# Can someone explain this error with the wait_for() function in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a Wordle discord bot however this error keeps occuring.

```
   async def playwordle(ctx):
  word_list = []
  word_file = open("wordle_words.txt")
  for word in word_file:
    word_list.append(word.strip())

  wordle_answer = random.choice(word_list)
  guess_num = 0
  guess_correct = False

  while guess_num < 6 and not guess_correct:
    msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda m: m.author==ctx.author and m.channel==ctx.channel)
    ctx.send(msg)
    guess_num += 1
    guess_correct = processGuess(ctx, wordle_answer, msg)
```

And I get the error "TypeError: wait_for() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'". I've tried every solution I can find but none seem applicable to me. Thanks!

Comment: The error is exactly what it's telling you. You're missing one argument (timeout).
            msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=60.0, check=check)

Comment: Thanks but this still throws up the same error.